# How to create a progress bar with aiometer's run_all method?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, progress-bar, python-asyncio

I've been creating a pipeline from an API using httpx, asyncio and aiometer to limit the number of coroutines running at once.

I know that it's possible to create a async progress bar for asyncio's gather method, however i didn't find anything about doing the same with aiometer's run_all.

Here's the main function used:

```
from functools import partial
from asyncio import run
from aiometer import run_all

async def main():
    result_donations = run_all(
        [partial(ApiGuara.get_donations, page) for page in range(50)],
        max_at_once=10
        )
    await result_donations

run(main())
```

The method "get_donations" is an async method that gets the data from the api and inserts in the datalake.

```
async def get_donations(self, page:int) -> None:
        async with AsyncClient(
            base_url=f'{self.url}',
            headers=self.headers,
            timeout=None) as asyncclient:
            try:
                r = await asyncclient.get(f'/donations?page={page}')
                donations_json = r.json()['data']
                for donation in donations_json:
                    donation['_id'] = donation.pop('id')
                    try:
                        #DONATIONS_COLLECTION.insert_one(donation)
                        pass
                    except errors.DuplicateKeyError:
                        pass
            finally:
                await asyncclient.aclose()
```

I tried using tqdm just like it is used with asyncio, however it is not working properly with aiometer.

Does anyone knows how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Note: the goal here is to track the progress of the coroutines at "result_donations".

Comment: I had a similar usecase but I was using `aiometer.run_on_each` - in my case I simply wrapped the iterator in tqdm i.e. `result = await aiometer.run_on_each(partial(my_func, headers=HEADERS), tqdm(to_process),max_per_second=10, max_at_once=10)`. In your case try